# Calculus of variations: Extremal classification, prove there is no sup(I)

Tags: calculus, calculus-of-variations, euler-lagrange-equation

I am trying to understand calculus of variations. I have  $I(y)=\int_1^2(x^2y'^2+2y^2)dx$ and boundary conditions $y(1)=4$ and $y(2)=1$. I have to find extremal $y_0$ od the functional $I(y)$. I started that with EL equation for $\mathcal{L}=x^2y'^2+2y^2$:
$$
\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial y'}\right) = \frac{\mathcal{L}}{dy}.
$$
I get the differential equation $4y=4xy'+2x^2y''$, which I than simplified to $x^2y''+2xy'-2y=0$ and solved for $y=x^{\lambda x}$. The solution is $y=C_1x+C_2x^{-1}$, and after evaluating for boundary conditions I get $y_0=\frac{4}{x^2}$.

Now I would like to know if $y_0$ is min or max of functional $I$. I know from the textbook, that $y_0$ is min, but I do not understand how can I determine that. I would also like to know, how to prove, that functional $I(y)$ doesn't have supremum, eg. $sup(I(y))$ doesn't exist. How do one show that?

Comment: An intuitive reason for why the supremum doesn't exist is that you can make $y'$ to be as steep as possible (for example, make $y$ a series of very steep jagged lines) while preserving the integral of $y^2$ over the region. This makes $|y'|$ arbitrarily large, and hence the integrand can be arbitrarily large, so there is no max. As for the first question, I'm not completely familiar with classifying the extremum, but is there a reason that $y_0$ can't be a saddle point/point of inflection?

Comment: I have to determine if this is minimum or maximum.

Comment: Also, do I have to prove that $y_0$ is really the extrem? As l understand EL equations gives necessary condition for extrem to occur, but not sufficient one?

Answer (score 1):

Without boundary conditions considerations we have that $y = c_1x+\frac{c_2}{x^2}$ is the solution for the Euler-Lagrange equation $x^2 y''+2x y'-2y=0$. Now substituting the solution into the integral we have

$$
I(y) = \frac{14 c_1^2}{3}+c_1 c_2 \log (16)+\frac{7 c_1}{3}+\frac{7 c_2^2}{12}-\text{c2} \ln(4)
$$

which is a quadratic form with minimum but not maximum (depending on $c_1,c_2$)